# Use github pages to host a production website

Tags: github, github-pages

I've been using github pages in order to showcase my progress on a simple website I am building but now I saw the option to assign a DNS name to the repository.

This made me think that I could actually avoid buying a service (hostgator, bluehost etc) and actually host my site in github pages.

What is your recommendation on this? Is github pages used for this kind of purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Github Page is a great place for you to host a static website. All you need to do is to purchase a domain and configure the DNS. Basically, it is a free hosting service I think you can put it that way.

Here is a tutorial on how to set up your Github Page with a custom domain: https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. I mean this can save around 70 dollars (minimum)/year for hosting services. But I still wonder if this is the proper way to do things when you want to have something in production.

Comment: Given the fact that you would like a simple website to showcase your work, I would say this is suitable. For example, `docker` hosts its `documentation` on GitHub page using markdown and that is a production website. Many people host their static blogs on GitHub page as well. Good luck!

Comment: You can make your GitHub pages dynamic with jsdelivr